# Open Source Communication Module with PDF generation

Tags: mit, communication

I have a requirement where I need to send html template based emails and also attach some pdf which is dynamically generated from some more templates.

This seems to be the most common requirements of any telecom, banking, ERP, etc domain applications. To be able to send such communications.

is there any open source application/micro-service available which i can use for my projects as well..?

I am currently trying to do the same in GO but the available libraries for pdf generation are not that much mature...

Comment: for those who downvote please share some reason as well....

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are many. I will list just a few below.

If you want it to look gorgeous then use Latex. It is slow to render, but looks great.

There is also pandoc, it can produce html, PDF (needs Latex), ODT, RTF, docx, and many others.

Open/Libre office can also create pdf, and can be automated.

The only other PDF generators that I have used, are for creating graphs, and pictures. But there are many many others.